# Dynamic SQL for updating a table from ASP .NET

Tags: .net, sql, orm, dynamic-sql

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 application that I want to allow the user to select a table and allow CRUD operations on that table. The user will be restricted to a number of tables to edit however the tables and even database won't be known until after deployment; the web.config will setup the connection and tables.

So I need to build a framework that will allow a generic table in a SQL database to be updated. Most of the ORMs I've seen require the schema to be known at compile time so I cannot use these. The best answer seems to be build the SQL query strings dynamically and use reg expressions to ensure valid input and protect against SQL injections. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. How about dataset and datatable objects? you can populate these via a dynamic sql statement, bind them directly to a good editor grid control, and the schema and column data type checking should be a snap. What did we ever do before ORM's and Linq?!?!

Answer (score 0):

The Dynamic Linq Library is incredible.  You can specify everything as a string, except maybe the table names.

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/step2.png))</sub>
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

However, look here for ideas on how to select tables at runtime by dynamically mapping the DataContext:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/09/27/25294.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use JJMasterData to dynamic generate SQL scripts for all CRUD operations from a table. We support both .NET 6 and .NET Framework 4.8.

https://www.github.com/jjconsulting/JJMasterData