# Show/Hide Column According to stored procedure parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server

currently working in report module in a system 
it's required to make user choose (from page) the columns to show

Example 
Page

```
[X]Column1
[ ]Column2
[X]Column3

Table returned from SP

---------------------
| Column1 | Column3 |
---------------------
|         |         |
---------------------
```

Page

```
[ ]Column1
[X]Column2
[ ]Column3

Table returned from SP

-----------
| Column2 |
-----------
|         |
-----------
```

### how to achieve something like that using VC# and sql server 2008 with stored procedures ?

Edit : i know how to fix it using Dynamic SQL statements put i asking about way better than that

Comment: This can be handled by using dynamic SQL.
But what about the report?.Are you using any kind of report engine like Crystal/SSRS ?

Comment: kindly have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923907/dynamic-sql-for-updating-a-table-from-asp-net

Comment: @Appyks : i don't need to use dynamic SQL cuz many ppl advice to avoid using it due to performance issues , and no there os no report engines the report should be exported in Excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check this article [How to Create a Complete Dynamic SQL Statement Using SQL Server](http://aspalliance.com/945_CodeSnip_How_to_Create_a_Complete_Dynamic_SQL_Statement_Using_SQL_Server.all)

In that article you can get an idea to build simple dynamic SQL statement with dynamic list of fields to display and dynamic `where` statement.

Comment: is there any way better than dynamic SQL ?